# External IP address without port results to "The request timed out"

Tags: networking, ip, port-forwarding, http

I have set up a HTTP server on my home machine and a port forwarding rule on my router. These work just fine when I visit my external IP address with the specified port (like `xx.xx.xx.xx:8080`), but if I enter just my external IP address I get "Request Timed Out".

How can I "explain" to my router that when it gets a request for the IP without port, it should forward it to `IP:8080`?

Comment: PS: I am using XAMPP

Comment: @Kamil It seems you have a point. I tried forwarding port 80 to 8080 and i get the expected results. i did not know that http uses port 80 by default even if you don't specify it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your client (a browser) uses the default port when it tries to connect. If it's HTTP then the port is TCP 80.

Either tell your client to use 8080 or tell your router to forward 80 to 8080. The latter is usually the right way and most routers can do this.

Now you're forwarding `router_external_IP:8080` to `server_LAN_IP:8080`. Configure the router to forward `router_external_IP:80` to `server_LAN_IP:8080`.

This is rather unlikely but if your router can only forward a port *without* changing its numerical value, then you should configure the server to listen on port 80 and forward this port.